# Issue while inserting images to the mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to insert an image from windows application to mysql database , it has been executed succesfully but there exists no data in my table.

Here I have used the following code. The execution is successful, according to my table email id and image must must be stored in table , but both the fields are saved as empty.

```
 public void LoadImages()
        {
            MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
            cn.Open();
            string image = txtLogo.Text;
            byte[] ImageData;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(image, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

            ImageData = BitConverter.GetBytes(fs.Length); 
            br.Close();
            fs.Close();
            MySqlParameter parImage = new MySqlParameter();
            parImage.ParameterName = "?Images";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into Fn_Pictures(Images,Email)values(?Images,'" + txtEmailIdText + "')", cn);
            parImage.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.MediumBlob;
            parImage.Size = 3000000;
            parImage.Value = ImageData;//here you should put your byte []

            cmd.Parameters.Add(parImage);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Try increasing the size

Comment: Yes Vignesh Kumar I have debugged code and txtEmailIdText.Text is entered as null

Answer (score 0):

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(fs.Length);
```

This returns the length as a byte[4], not reads the image data.
Take a look here for reading the file:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You probably also want to set parImage.Size to ImageData.length, not 3000000.

Comment: i have tried u r suggestion but no use...@Hunter Guy

Comment: @user3531533 Put a break Point and check did you get value or not in both `txtEmailIdText.Text` and `ImageData`

Comment: Yes Vignesh Kumar I have debugged code and txtEmailIdText.Text is entered as null